# Calculating a probability based on several variables in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I'm still very new to Python and Pandas, so bear with me...

I have a dataframe of passengers on a ship that sunk. I have broken this down into other dataframes by male and female, and also by class to create probabilities for survival. I made a function that compares one dataframe to a dataframe of only survivors, and calculates the probability of survival among this group:

```
def survivability(total_pass_df, column, value):
    survivors = sum(did_survive[column] == value)
    total = len(total_pass_df)
    survival_prob = round((survivors / total), 2)
    return survival_prob
```

But now I'm trying to compare survivability among smaller groups - male first class passengers vs female third class passengers for example. I did make dataframes for both of these groups, but I still can't use my survivability function because I"m comparing two different columns - sex and class - rather than just one.

I know exactly how I'd do it with Python - loop through the 'survived' column (which is either a 1 or 0), in the dataframe, if it equals 1, then add one to an index value, and once all the data has been gone through, divide the index value by the length of the dataframe to get the probability of survival....

But I'm supposed to use Pandas for this, and I can't for the life of me work out in my head how to do it....

:/

Answer (score 1):

Without a sample of the data frames you're working with, I can't be sure if I understand your question correctly. But based on your description of the pure-Python procedure,

> I know exactly how I'd do it with Python - loop through the 'survived' column (which is either a 1 or 0), in the dataframe, if it equals 1, then add one to an index value, and once all the data has been gone through, divide the index value by the length of the dataframe to get the probability of survival....

you can do this in Pandas by simply writing

```
dataframe['survived'].mean()
```

That's it. Given that all the values are either 1 or 0, the mean will be the number of 1's divided by the total number of rows.

If you start out with a data frame that has columns like `survived`, `sex`, `class`, and so on, you can elegantly combine this with Pandas' boolean indexing to pick out the survival rates for different groups. Let me use the [Socialcops Titanic passengers data set](https://blog.socialcops.com/engineering/machine-learning-python/) as an example to demonstrate. Assuming the `DataFrame` is called `df`, if you want to analyze only male passengers, you can get those records as

```
df[df['sex'] == 'male']
```

and then you can take the `survived` column of *that* and get the mean.

```
>>> df[df['sex'] == 'male']['survived'].mean()
0.19198457888493475
```

So 19% of male passengers survived. If you want to narrow down to male second-class passengers, you'll need to combine the conditions using `&`, like this:

```
>>> df[(df['sex'] == 'male') & (df['pclass'] == 2)]['survived'].mean()
0.14619883040935672
```

This is getting a little unwieldy, but there's an easier way that actually lets you do multiple categories at once. (The catch is that this is a somewhat more advanced Pandas technique and it might take a while to understand it.) Using the [`DataFrame.groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) method, you can tell Pandas to group the rows of the data frame according to their values in certain columns. For example,

```
df.groupby('sex')
```

tells Pandas to group the rows by their sex: all male passengers' records are in one group, and all female passengers' records are in another group. The thing you get from `groupby()` is not a `DataFrame`, it's a special kind of object that lets you apply aggregation functions - that is, functions which take a whole group and turn it into one number (or something). So, for example, if you do this

```
>>> df.groupby('sex').mean()
          pclass  survived        age     sibsp     parch       fare  \
sex                                                                    
female  2.154506  0.727468  28.687071  0.652361  0.633047  46.198097   
male    2.372479  0.190985  30.585233  0.413998  0.247924  26.154601   

             body  
sex                
female  166.62500  
male    160.39823
```

you see that for each column, Pandas takes the average over the male passengers' records of all that column's values, and also over all the female passenger's records. All you care about here is the survival rate, so just use

```
>>> df.groupby('sex').mean()['survived']
sex
female    0.727468
male      0.190985
```

One big advantage of this is that you can give more than one column to group by, if you want to look at small groups. For example, sex and class:

```
>>> df.groupby(['sex', 'pclass']).mean()['survived']
sex     pclass
female  1         0.965278
        2         0.886792
        3         0.490741
male    1         0.340782
        2         0.146199
        3         0.152130
```

(you have to give `groupby` a list of column names if you're giving more than one)

Comment: Oh wow....I didn't even think about just taking the mean of survival...I was trying to find a way to use groupby() in this problem, but I still find it kind of confusing.

Comment: It is confusing, don't worry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried merging the two dataframes by passenger ID and then doing a pivot table in Pandas with whatever row subtotals and aggfunc=numpy.mean?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Passenger List
p_list = pd.DataFrame()
p_list['ID'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
p_list['Class'] = ['1','2','2','1','2','1']
p_list['Gender'] = ['M','M','F','F','F','F']

# Survivor List
s_list = pd.DataFrame()
s_list['ID'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
s_list['Survived'] = [1,0,0,0,1,0]

# Merge the datasets
merged = pd.merge(p_list,s_list,how='left',on=['ID'])

# Pivot to get sub means
result = pd.pivot_table(merged,index=['Class','Gender'],values=['Survived'],aggfunc=np.mean,  margins=True)

# Reset the index
for x in range(result.index.nlevels-1,-1,-1):
    result.reset_index(level=x,inplace=True)
print result

  Class Gender  Survived
0     1      F  0.000000
1     1      M  1.000000
2     2      F  0.500000
3     2      M  0.000000
4   All         0.333333
```